# Ricci flow on a manifold: How does the manifold itself change?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

I'm new to this subject, and I'm a bit confused about how the metric changing corresponds to the manifold itself changing. For example, in [Topping's](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaseq/topping_RF_mar06.pdf) note it says:

> A simple example of a Ricci flow is that starting from a round sphere. This
> will evolve by shrinking homothetically to a point in finite time.

When I first looked at the equation $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=-2Ric(g)$, I thought that on a fixed manifold, we are defining the metrics $g_t$. But all the figures in chapter 1 suggest that the manifold itself is changing.

Also, if the manifold is changing, how can we define fixed vector fields (independent of time) on it, like Topping's note does in chapter 2?

Comment: if a Riemannian manifold is embedded in Euclidean space, and the metric changes, the embedding must have changed.

Comment: You’re right. The manifold does not change topologically. The Riemannian metric changes but that’s saying the same thing as saying the Riemannian manifold changes. The quoted statement means simply that in finite time the metric tensor on the fixed topological manifold converges to the zero tensor.